# setmethod for an object in Array which is Serializable

Tags: java, arrays, object, serialization

I have a Class Passenger which is serializable.

```
public class Passenger implements Serializable
 { 
    private String fullName;

public Passenger(String fullName);{
  this.fullName = fullName;
   }

public String getFullName(){
  return fullName;
}

public void setFullName(String fullName) {
  this.fullName = fullName;
 }
}
```

In the other class I would like to use `setFullName` method, change the  name and afterwards display the new name.

```
public class CreatePassangerEdit
 {
  private JTextField user;

public CreatePassangerEdit(){
 createPassangerEditWindow();
  }

public void createPassangerEditWindow(){
 Database db = Persistence.loadDatabase();

  for (int i = 0; i < db.getPassengers().size(); i++){
   Passenger passenger = db.getPassengers().get(i);
    if(passenger.getUser().equals(LoginWindow2.getLogin1()) &&passenger.getPassword().equals(LoginWindow2.getPassword222())){
      passenger.setFullName(user.getText());
      System.out.println("your name has been changed");
      System.out.println(passenger.getFullName()); //it's printing out old name
      i = db.getPassengers().size();
  }
}
```

Unfortunately if I try to get passenger name I'm getting the old name.

Comment: You need to reserialize the object?

Comment: i don't know i just want to change the name of existing object